# How to get DataTextField of DropDownList in javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

I am using a DropDownList as

```
<asp:DropDownList 
  ID="ddlLocationName" 
  runat="server" 
  DataValueField="Guid" 
  DataTextField="LocationName" 
  AppendDataBoundItems="false" 
  AutoPostBack="false" 
  onchange="LocationChange()"
></asp:DropDownList>
```

and when I select item from dropdown the DataTextField should be displayed in the textfield. For that i am using following javascript:

```
function LocationChange()
{  
  document.getElementById ("ctl00_mainContent_ctl02_txtEventLocation").value = document.getElementById ('ctl00_mainContent_ctl02_ddlLocationName')[document.getElementById ('ctl00_mainContent_ctl02_ddlLocationName').selectedIndex].value     
}
```

It works fine when dropdown's DataValueField is not used. But how to do desired task when DataValueField property of dropdown is also used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why asp tag of dropdown is not displayed in question? Can anyone tell me please how to display that tag?

Comment: Have a read of the wiki on formatting. You probably didn't wrap it in the appropriate code block. I edited to put the JS function into code appropriately for readability.

Answer (score 3):

The DataValueField will populate the html `<option />` tags value property, while the DataTextField will populate the text property.

When you *don't* specify a DataValueField the DataTextField is used for both (and vice-versa IIRC).

So in JavaScript you'll want to have the following (**note - I'm using the MS AJAX shorthand where $get === document.getElementById**):

```
function LocationChange(){
  var ddl = $get('dropDownListId');
  var selectedOption = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex];
  var selectedText = selectedOption.text;
  var selectedValue = selectedOption.value;

  alert('Your option has a text property of ' + selectedText + ' and a value property of ' + selectedValue');
}
```

Then you can do what ever you want with the results, such as putting them into a text box.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replys.
I found answer.

```
function LocationChange()
{  
    document.getElementById ("ctl00_mainContent_ctl02_txtEventLocation").value = document.getElementById ('ctl00_mainContent_ctl02_ddlLocationName')[document.getElementById ('ctl00_mainContent_ctl02_ddlLocationName').selectedIndex].innerText
}
```

Comment: Good solution, I think you have found when you see rendered html